# Android http post not sending data

Tags: android, json, post, web, http-post

Firstly, I'm receiving the status code 200. In the php script I'm just having the code mail me whats being sent to the server (whilst I try and debug). Using var_dump $_POST or $_REQUEST I get a blank email. If I run a foreach on $_SERVER I get some data back like HTTP_USER_AGENT : Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4) and CONTENT_LENGTH : 9

I don't understand why there's no post data? I'm new to android, I'm literally learning as I go.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(dest_url);
    //httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

//JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        // Add your data
        //json.put("action", "login");
        //json.put("username", "kermit");
        //json.put("password", "123456");

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myjson", json.toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plswork", "hi"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

    //StringEntity str_json = new StringEntity(json.toString());

    //httppost.setEntity(str_json);
    HttpResponse response;

    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

My manifestxml has the following line;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

These are my imports;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it has something to do with your

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

`application/json` is not a normal content type for HTTP POST form submission.  Considering that you're not really sending json but rather a standard POST entity (nameString=valueString), try changing this to

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

and see whether this will sort your issue.  Or better yet, remove it alltogether.

I use this code in my app - and it works perfectly fine:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("REQUEST", req));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The response in this case is `text/xml` - but this shouldn't matter.

Comment: I've already commented out that line. I added what you said to put but it to makes no difference.

Comment: @I.am.Will Just out of curiosity, try commenting out all `setHeader` lines.  Leave just the constructor for the post and setting the entity - and then execute the post.  Also make sure your PHP code is correct - maybe it does receive the request but you're not forwarding it correctly.

Comment: Made no difference I'm afraid. My php file for testing purposes contains;
<?php $string = var_dump($_REQUEST);
    
    mail('myemail@address.com', 'Droid Login', $string, 'From: My <my@address.com>'); ?>

Comment: @I.am.Will There's your problem: `var_dump` is a `void` function - it doesn't return anything, therefore assigning its return value into `$string` will make that string blank.  Instead use: `$string = print_r($_REQUEST, true);`

Comment: Setting the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` did the trick for me.